# SQLite Group by last seven days (not weekly!)

Tags: sqlite, date

I was looking some GROUP BY questions here but no one is like mine.

I have a current table like this:

```
|day   |  client|
----------------
|2020-01-07|id11|
|2020-01-07|id10|
|2020-01-06|id09|
|2020-01-06|id08|
|2020-01-05|id07|
|2020-01-04|id06|
|2020-01-03|id05|
|2020-01-03|id04|
|2020-01-02|id03|
|2020-01-01|id02|
|2020-01-01|id01|
```

And I want to create a new column with the ocurrences of unique clients for the last seven days (day - 6) (not weekly!) and show it by day:

```
|day   |last 7 day clients|
----------------
|2020-01-07|11|
|2020-01-06| 9|
|2020-01-05| 7|
|2020-01-04| 6|
|2020-01-03| 5|
|2020-01-02| 3|
|2020-01-01| 2|
```

All the aswers here are grouping weekly!

What I tryed:

```
pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT DATE(day) dateColumn,  
                            COUNT(DISTINCT client) AS seven_day_users
                    FROM table
                    GROUP BY date(dateColumn, '-6 days')
                    ORDER BY dateColumn DESC;
                        """, conn)
```

But the result is grouping by day, not into the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self join of the table and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.day,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.client) `last 7 day clients`
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.day BETWEEN date(t1.day, '-6 day') AND t1.day
GROUP BY t1.day
ORDER BY t1.day DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=872ffa35fa16d26516968eca4633a2ec).

Comment: I thougt it was right, but there is still a problem: I don't want the ```CURRENT_DATE```, but the ```day``` - 6

Comment: @jvqp if you want the days from current date - 6 days until yesterday then you want the last 6 and not last 7 days. Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: No, I don't want the current date or six days before the current date. What I want is six days before the day in my table

Comment: sorry, you are right, I will re-write it

Comment: @jvqp see my edited answer.

Comment: I don't understand, you created a second table t2 in this answer?

Comment: @jvqp no, this is called a self join of the same table.